# Why won't my PS3 recognize any of my controllers?

Tags: ps3, controllers

Few days ago my PS3 decided to stop recognizing my controllers. When I press the PS Button, nothing happens, regardless of whether or not DualShock is connected through a USB cable or Bluetooth. I've checked a few different controllers, but none of them work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try connecting the Controller, via packaged / 'came-with' USB-Cables, to the PlayStation: like @Luc_M suggested.
Or, maybe try re-charging from a computer's USB Port.

These suggestions come from standardised procedures. :)

Comment: Still nothing, controller is fully charged. It's like PS3 is not recognizing standard controller however additional controller is working without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your Dualshock 3 controller might have lost its binding to your console.

Try [resetting the controller](https://support.us.playstation.com/articles/en_US/KC_Article/Troubleshoot-DUALSHOCK-3-SIXAXIS-Controllers) by pushing the reset button (you will need something thin and long, e.g. a paperclip). The reset button is located on the back of the Dualshock 3, near the L2 button inside a small hole.

After that, resync the controller to your PS3 by first connecting it with the USB cable.